# How to make random.nextInt() repeat an already generated digit only when others have been generated

Tags: android

Lets say i want to generate numbers ranging from 0 to 5,  i want to make random.nextInt(5) to first generate all numbers before repeating any of them for example  0,3,1,5,2,4 then repeat but not with the digit which is (4). I'm okay with any how the numbers are generated. I only know how to randomize everything.

Comment: `random.nextInt(5)` be aware that the domain is `[0, 5)` and not `[0, 5]`

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    Collections.shuffle(numbers);
    for (int n : numbers) {
        // numbers will be in random order here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by breaking the problem in two parts.
1. Generate all no upto 6
2. Generate random number which is not same as previous one.

> 1. Create one boolean array which will keep track of which no have been generated.
> 2. Create on int to keep track of previous no generated.
> 3. Create one boolean variable for following up with solution 2nd part easily. So that you don't need to check everytime once all the numbers are genrated in range.

```
boolean[] arrRange= new boolean[6];
boolean isRangeGenerated = false;
int lastNoGenerated = 0;
Random rand;
```

Method for generating number.

```
private void generateNumber() {
    if(!isRangeGenerated){  //this is 1st part of solution
        int pos = rand.nextInt(6);
        while(arrRange[pos]){
            pos = rand.nextInt(6);
        }
        lastNoGenerated = pos;
        arrRange[pos]=true;

        isRangeGenerated = checkAllNumbergenrated(arrRange);
        System.out.println(pos);
    }else {                    //this is 2nd part of solution
        int newNum = rand.nextInt(6);
        while(newNum == lastNoGenerated){
            newNum = rand.nextInt(6);
        }
        lastNoGenerated = newNum;
        System.out.println(newNum);
    }
}
```

Method for checking if all number in range are generated

```
private boolean checkAllNumbergenrated(boolean[] arrRange) {

    for(int i=0;i<arrRange.length;i++){
        if(!arrRange[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```